# Input loses event after include a tr

Tags: jquery, events, dom, bind

I'm using the `.on()` method to bind the following events to a input:

```
$('table.transactions tbody input').on({
    "focus": function (e) { $(this).closest('tr').addClass('active'); },
    "blur": function (e) { $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('active'); }
});
```

When I include a new tr on the table, the new input loses the focus and blur events:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function (e) {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    $tr.after('<tr><td><input type="text" /><a href="" class="btn">Add Tr</a></td></tr>');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

As I'm using `.on()` method, the focus and blur events to the new input shouldn't be automatically? If not, how do I bind the events again?

Comment: The keyword is "event delegation" (i know makes two), see @Steven Vondruska 's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using delegation on a stable element to pick up newly added elements

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(e) {
    // event data here
}
```

You can change `document` to the containing element, maybe the table that contains the `<tr>` you're adding.

ref: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: the click event of '.btn' is working fine, the problem is on input blur and focus events

Comment: I did it using: $('table.transactions tbody').on('focus', 'input', function (e) {